# nginx+PHP+Windows .php script not running the lines where there is no error

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to run this simple PHP script in nginx which has one line without any error and a line with a deliberate error.

```
<?php
     echo "ABCD";
     echo "DEFG;
?>
```

My nginx.conf has the following

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

 #pid        logs/nginx.pid;


 events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ .php$ {
    root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

}
```

In Apache Server I could run the above script and it prints the first line which has no error and then stops. But in nginx the same script does not run at all and stops. I have not changed any other configuration files in nginx or PHP.

I want to know how to run the run the whole script even if there is some error in the middle of a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an ordinary execution error; it's a syntax error. The parser can't tell how to parse your script, so it dies before executing any of your code.

Please note that this is the safest course of action for the parser to take. If it tried to guess where the missing `"` was, you could inadvertently execute something that should have been treated as, say, a string literal.

Comment: At least it should print the first line? No? and then stop. The first line has no error.

Comment: Think about it. This would almost certainly lead to data corruption and other inconsistencies in a real program. Better for it to die without potentially making a mess first.